# storing user hashed password into webauthn id

Tags: web-application, webauthn, web-authentication

I am building a pure client-side app.
My users have a `.kdbx` vault stored in localStorage, and they can open it with a password.

In order to add a biometric\quick open feature into the app I thought about creating a Webauthn entry and storing the user-hashed password into the `id` field of it.

Later when calling verify, I will get this hashed password from the `id` response, and use it to open the vault.

I have seen several comments about not storing sensitive data in the `id` field, but can't find any evidence or description of an attack vector that can make it insecure.

What do you smart people think about it?

Comment: Welcome to the community. So it's purely client-side without a secret on the server-side like it's usually made for more security?

Comment: It's just a PWA app, so no server side because I don't need any. :-)